# mySQL count occurances of value on multiple fields. How?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 5 fields. Each field can store a number from 1 - 59.

Similar to countif in Excel, how do I count the number of times a number from 1 - 59 shows up in all 5 fields?

Here's an example for the count of occurances for the number 1 in all five fields:

```
SELECT SUM(pick_1 = 1 OR pick_2 = 1 OR pick_3 = 1 OR pick_4 = 1 OR pick_5 = 1) AS total_count_1
FROM tbldraw
```

Hopefully I made sense.

Comment: What do you want you output to look like?  59 rows (1 per digit)  with how often in your table that value shows up in all five fields of a record)?

Comment: Wasn't there an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an answer here that had a solution.  I think this is just a variation.

Step1:  Create a numbers table (1 field, called id, 59 records (values 1 -59))

Step2:

```
SELECT numbers_table.number as number
  , COUNT(tbldraw.pk_record)
FROM numbers_table
LEFT JOIN tbldraw
 ON numbers_table.number = tbldraw.pick_1
   OR numbers_table.number = tbldraw.pick_2
   OR numbers_table.number = tbldraw.pick_3
   OR numbers_table.number = tbldraw.pick_4
   OR numbers_table.number = tbldraw.pick_5
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a two step process? Assuming a table called `summary_table ( int id, int ttl)`, for each number you care about...

```
insert into summary_table values (1,
    (select count(*)
     from table
     where field1 = 1 or field2 = 1 or field3 = 1 or field4 = 1 or field5 = 1))
```

do that 59 times, once for each value.  You can use a loop in most cases. Then you can select from the summary_table

```
select *
from summary_table
order by id
```

That will do it.  I leave the coversion of this SQL into a stored procedure for those that know what database is in use.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ALL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html) function, which returns `true` if the preceding operator is `true` for all parameters, makes the query particularly elegant and succinct.

To find the count a particular number (eg 3):

```
select count(*)
from tbldraw
where 3 = all (pick_1, pick_2, pick_3, pick_4, pick_5)
```

To find the count of *all* such numbers:

```
select pick_1, count(*)
from tbldraw
where pick_1 = all (pick_2, pick_3, pick_4, pick_5)
group by pick_1
```